# Regex use OR to add part for links

Tags: regex

I have want to have a regex that works for single link or separate parts.

**If I put single link:**

```
https://example.com/file.rar
```

Replace with

```
[url=https://example.com/file.rar]Example[/url]
```

**If I put many parts:**

```
https://example.com/file.part1.rar
https://example.com/file.part2.rar
```

Replace with

```
[url=https://example.com/file.part1.rar]Example Part 1[/url]
[url=https://example.com/file.part2.rar]Example Part 2[/url]
```

Really appreciate your helps.

Comment: what is your regex what is your inputs, can you provide a example?

Comment: @YCF_L I'm using Sublime Text

Comment: ok provide an inputs that you want to match and what is your regex that you try to do?

Comment: @YCF_L These are 2 separates regex. If I put single link I have to use no.1 regex, e.g: [example link](https://example.com/file/file.rar). Now I want to use `OR` in regex to check if I put link that has many parts, e.g: [example link 2](https://example.com/file/file.part1.rar), it will use no.2 regex.

Comment: It is not quite clear how these regexps work together. Do you mean `.+` in `https://abc\.com.+?part([0-9]+?)\.rar` should match only if after `.com` there is a whitespace? What is the order you execute the regexps? A set of clearly explained requirements would make it easier to answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew These are 2 separates regex. If I put single link I have to use no.1 regex, e.g: [example link](https://example.com/file/file.rar). Now I want to use `OR` in regex to check if I put link that has many parts, e.g: [example link 2](https://example.com/file/file.part1.rar), it will use no.2 regex.

Comment: Do not copy the comments, put the relevant details into the question. You did not explain how the regexps are run. Please do in the question. The problem is that the regexps may match the same parts of text (at the same location).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated question, hope that clear.

Comment: Ok, you want to exract `example`, `part` and `1` and build the link name out of them? Are these URLs standalone strings or part of a longer string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew part of a longer string

Comment: So, you need: 1) domain name (and that is an immense problem actually), 2) the last subpart of the path that should be split with `.` and each part must be capitalized? Sorry, that is rather broad.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yea, right. You can take a look my example for more details